# Return count(*) from MySql gives syntax error in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I struggle to solve a problem, but I can't understand what is wrong.
I have defined the StoredProcedure﻿(below). When I call it from the command-line, it works as expected. But when I call it from my java-class (below) it gives an erreor (below). I have debugged, the in parameters have the expected values.
I really hope someone can help me. Thanks !

**error :**

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '()' at line 1

**JAVA procedure calling Stored Procedure:**

```
boolean CheckProjectExistence(String dbname, int projectid){              
        try(Connection con = init();
            CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{call sp_project_exists(?,?}"))
        {       
            stmt.setString(1,dbname);
            stmt.setInt(2, projectid);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
              stmt.getInt("count");
            }
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("Feil med GeneralDAO.CheckProjectExistence "+   ex.getMessage());
        }   

        return false;
    }
```

**MySQL 5.6.30 Stored Procedure definition:**

```
USE PP_Master;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_project_exists`; 

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_project_exists (IN p_dbname VARCHAR(30),IN p_projectid INT)
BEGIN

SET @tableName = concat(p_dbname, '.Project');

SET @sql_text = 
concat('SELECT COUNT(ProjectId) AS count FROM ',
@tableName, ' WHERE ProjectId=', p_projectid, ';');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;  

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: why dont you close your brackets where you call function?

Comment: {call sp_project_exists(?,?} -> {call sp_project_exists(?,?)}

Answer (score 1):

Just change the following line...

```
CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{call sp_project_exists(?,?}"))
```

to

```
CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{call sp_project_exists(?,?)}"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't see that typo before you pointed it out. Now I got another error, but I hope I'm able to solve that.